# JAX-WS method's Decimal field is NULL when String value is passed

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, decimal, bigdecimal

I have Jaxws Soap web service. My **"myMethod"** method have a decimal type field.

Here is my web service interface:

```
@WebService(name = "myWs", targetNamespace = "someNamespace")
@Local 
public interface myWsPortType {     
    @WebMethod  
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "myMethod", className = "com.example.MyMethodRequest")  
    public Result myMethod(@WebParam(name = "parameters", mode = Mode.IN) MyMethodParameters parameters); 
}
```

This is parameter class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType()
public class MyMethodParameters implements java.io.Serializable {
    @FieldValidation(maxLength = 12)
    @XmlElement(name = "myField", required = false)
    private java.math.BigDecimal myField;
}
```

Everything works correctly when I pass Correct type of data in **myField**.

But, the problem is that when I call **myMethod** and pass String value (instead of Decimal) as parameter no exception is thrown and **myField**'s value is **null**

Here's Soap Request example

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <iss:myMethod>
         <parameters>
            <myField>test</myField>
         </parameters>
      </iss:myMethod>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I make my ws throw exception when incorrect data type is passed?

Comment: Does the XSD of your service indicates `myField` to be `xsd:decimal` ?

Comment: @AviramSegal Here is a snippet from my wsdl 
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="myField" type="xs:decimal"/>

Answer (score 3):

It lookls like the XSD Schema is generated just fine, what you are missing is the [SchemaValidation](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/developer/SchemaValidation.html) annotation to tell JAX-WS to validate the requests and responses with the schema.

Just add `@SchemaValidation` to your service:

```
@WebService(name = "myWs", targetNamespace = "someNamespace")
@SchemaValidation
@Local 
public interface myWsPortType { ... }
```

Comment: I added `@SchemaValidation`, but it still doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: There are 2 SchemaValidation annotation (one with internal in its package one without) did you try both of them ?